# How do you create a mixed-mode .NET assembly from scratch that can run on Windows?

Tags: .net, clr

The CLI - Annotated Standard clearly describes the structure of .NET assemblies as well as the binary structure MS-DOS Portable Executable files, but it doesn't mention anything about how to emit unmanaged code inside of a .NET assembly. Now, assuming that I am writing my own mixed-mode .NET compiler from scratch, are there any references or examples out there that show how to emit both x86 assembly and IL into a single .NET assembly?

Comment: .NET assemblies are still standard PE32 files.  And can therefore store native code sections as normal.

Comment: I'm aware that they're standard PE32/PE32+ files, but I'm looking for actual code samples that emit both the x86 assembly and IL into a single file.